# Symfony2 - How to get real server ip address?

Tags: symfony, http, request

I am currently using:

```
$this->request->server->get('SERVER_ADDR');
```

When the application is deployed to the real server, the value returned is 127.0.0.1, which is not correct. It should be the real ip address.

---

There seem to be a proxy there, since we had problems with getting the client ip address with:

```
$this->request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

I have fixed that I get client ip address using:

```
$this->request->getClientIp();
```

Maybe to get the real server ip address, there is also another more reliable way?

Comment: Dump out $SERVER and see if what you need is in there at all.  The request object is initialized using these globals.  I'm guessing it is more of a server config issue than a php issue.  If the ip is static then you could always just add it to parameters.yml.

Comment: Yes I did that. I found the server configuration was at fault and did not provide valid $_SERVER values.