# How to get my server IP in Symfony Command?

Tags: symfony, console, symfony-3.4, symfony-console

Are there any methods to get my server IP? I am writing a command where I need my server IP as parameter? 
Tried `request_stack` but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: Please check Cerads comment on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087613/symfony2-how-to-get-real-server-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

I think you can request an external resource that return your server IP, you can do this with this code in a Symfony command:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ipinfo.io/ip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$ip = curl_exec($ch);
```

I hope this can help you